# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException with ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener, actionevent

I'm encountering this error when trying to use an ActionListener to call a method that's in another class:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MainProgram.actionPerformed(MainProgram.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Most of the solutions for this error that I've found were that something in that line was null, and as far as I can tell that's not the case here (I'm probably wrong about that though).

What should happen is that when 'button1' (I know, bad practice) is clicked it should add 100 to Jim's cash, and update the JTextField 'jimBalance' to the new value.

Any other code I put in there works fine, until I call a method from the other class, even if it's just one line that returns true or something.

The error line (83) is the

```
jim.GiveCash(100.0, jimBalance);
```

line in the actionPerformed method.

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainProgram extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private static JTextField jimBalance;
    private static JTextField bobBalance;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JTextField jimPayment;
    private JTextField bobPayment;
    private Guy jim;
    private Guy bob;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainProgram mainWindow;
        mainWindow = new MainProgram();
        mainWindow.init();
        mainWindow.setSize(400,110);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

        Guy jim = new Guy();
        Guy bob = new Guy();

        jim.ReceiveCash(200, jimBalance);


        jimBalance.setText(String.valueOf(jim.cash()));
        bobBalance.setText(String.valueOf(bob.cash()));


    }

    public void init(){
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(null);
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setBounds(10,10,50,20);
        label1.setText("Jim");
        pane.add(label1);
        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setBounds(10,40,50,20);
        label2.setText("Bob");
        pane.add(label2);

        jimBalance = new JTextField();
        jimBalance.setBounds(50,10,100,20);
        jimBalance.setEditable(false);
        pane.add(jimBalance);
        bobBalance = new JTextField();
        bobBalance.setBounds(50,40,100,20);
        bobBalance.setEditable(false);
        pane.add(bobBalance);

        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setBounds(160,10,100,20);
        button1.setText("Give Bob");
        pane.add(button1);
        button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setBounds(160,40,100,20);
        button2.setText("Give Jim");
        pane.add(button2);

        button1.addActionListener(this);

        jimPayment = new JTextField();
        jimPayment.setBounds(270,10,100,20);
        pane.add(jimPayment);
        bobPayment = new JTextField();
        bobPayment.setBounds(270,40,100,20);
        pane.add(bobPayment);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        jim.GiveCash(100.0, jimBalance);
    }
}
```

And the Guy class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Guy {
    public String Name;
    public double cash;
    public void GiveCash(double amount, JTextField balance)
    {
        if((cash - amount) >= 0){
            cash = cash - amount;
            balance.setText(String.valueOf(cash));
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot afford that transaction!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void ReceiveCash(double amount, JTextField balance) { 
        cash = cash + amount;
        balance.setText(String.valueOf(cash));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following I show your problem:

At (1) you define the object variable `jim`.

At (2) you define a local variable in a static context.

At (3) `jim` is still `null` as this is a not initialized object variable which you cannot initialize from a static context (like the `main()` method).

```
public class MainProgram extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
// Omit some code
private Guy jim; // (1)
private Guy bob;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Omit some code

    Guy jim = new Guy(); // (2)
    Guy bob = new Guy();

    jim.ReceiveCash(200, jimBalance);

    // Omit some code
}

// Omit some code

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    jim.GiveCash(100.0, jimBalance); // (3)
}
```

}

Comment: Aha, thanks. How would I go about initialising jim and bob outside of the main method then? I tried initialising them on the same line as I declared them, but then I can't reference them from inside main().

Comment: @Murreey Please ask a new question (or better use the search as this question was asked already) how to access non static variables from the main method.